# SSH not exiting properly inside if statement in bash heredoc

Tags: bash, ssh, eof, heredoc

So i am running this script to check if a java server is up remotely by sshing into remote.  If it is down, i am trying to exit and run another script locally.  However, after the exit command, it is still in the remote directory.

```
ssh -i ec2-user@$DNS << EOF
    
    if !  lsof -i | grep -q java ; then
        echo "java server stopped running"
        # want to exit ssh
        exit
        # after here when i check it is still in ssh
        # I want to run another script locally in the same directory as the current script
        ./other_script.sh
    else
        echo "java server up"

    fi;
EOF
```

Comment: By issuing exit in the HEREDOC, you are exiting the ssh session and so will never get to the ./other_script.sh section. Should exit back to the local environment though and not the remote one

Comment: i've tried something like  "exit &" but that gets me back to the remote env.  Do you have any suggestion on how to deal with exiting the ssh?

Comment: Place this script in another one and when java is not running, exit with a number. Then when ssh exits, you can check the exit code in the script and run other_script if necessary

Comment: how would that look in bash?  outside of the heredoc do i use an if statement to check for exit code?  (this is currently in another script, just a piece of it tho)

Comment: Yes, indeed.....

Comment: so this can all be in the same script, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit is exiting the ssh session and so never gets to the execution of the other_script.sh line in the HEREDOC. It would be better to place this outside of the script and actioned from the exit status of the HEREDOC/ssh and so:

```
ssh -i ec2-user@$DNS << EOF

if !  lsof -i | grep -q java ; then
    echo "java server stopped running"
    exit 7   # Set the exit status to a number that isn't standard in case ssh fails
else
    echo "java server up"
fi;
EOF
if [[ $? -eq 7 ]]
then
    ./other_script.sh
fi
```

Comment: Thanks!! the only change i had to make was using -eq instead of == in the if statement